# help me minimize this sum

Tags: optimization

I want minimize $\sum_{i} ^{n} w_i^2$ such that $\sum_i ^{n} w_i=1$, and $w_i>0$

simply taking the derivative and set it to zero won't work. The answer is probably $w_i=1/n$, for all $i$. But I don't know how to show that.

Any thought on this?

Comment: use that $$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\geq \frac{a+b}{2}$$ and use this for $n$ variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2}\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$
can you proceed?